# Asp.net C#, monitor a c# function that checks the status from sql DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a "Refresh" button in update panel, onclick it fires an event which calls and starts a scheduler. Scheduler runs for some time, I need to show "In progress.." label instead of Refresh Button while the scheduler is running, once it completes the Button should be visible again.

I have a checkstatus() function which checks for status(select status...from table) in Database's Table if it completes or not. How do I monitor/call the checkstatus() continuously in order to show "In progress.." and once it finds the required status then show the button again ?

Please give me approach on this, I'll try to make it work.

Comment: Just before calling schedular to run in your `onclick` event handler change your button label and after your recieve response from server then in change it back.

Comment: Calling scheduler is different and checking the status function is different. I want to do this in updatepanel so user will see "In progress.." while the scheduler is running and is able to click any where else. I need to call checkstatus() to see what the status is and based on it's result enable the button again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a delegate and called that function recursively till the job is finished.